# WSO2BAM REST stream input to BAM/Cassandra; can't get to the EVENT_KS data using hive query?

Tags: hive, wso2, wso2-bam

The background for this question is essentially an [article written by Sachini Jayasekara](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/using-different-reporting-frameworks-wso2-business-activity-monitor/) @ WSO2 called ***Using Different Reporting Frameworks with WSO2 Business Activity Monitor*** . I am doing more or less exactly the same, but using rather the REST API to define a data stream and invoke the REST WS API to push data into BAM. Then use the HIVE queries to get to the data. However, it seems that I have missed something, as the attribute data is not shown. Hence the query.

Currently using the REST api which is invoked through a Perl based daemon. This invokes the REST API using the following streams definition and payload:

```
{
  "name":"currentcostRealtime2.stream",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "nickName": "Currentcost Realtime",
  "description": "This is the Currentcost realtime stream",
  "payloadData":[
    {
      "name":"sensor",
      "type":"INT"
    },
    {
      "name":"temp",
      "type":"FLOAT"
    },
    {
      "name":"timestamp",
      "type":"STRING"
    },
    {
      "name":"watt",
      "type":"INT"
    }
  ]
}
```

.. and payload definition ..

```
[
 {
   "payloadData" : [SENSOR, TEMP, "TIMESTAMP", WATT] ,
 }
]
```

I should note that the payload is string replaced before its committed; e.g. the actual payload that is committed looks like:

```
[
 {
   "payloadData" : [1, 18.7, "2014-06-15 16:15:56", 1] ,
 }
]
```

The queries execute with no apparent problem, but I am having now an issue with the HIVE query in BAM, which gives me entries output, but not the values. E.g. trying to now execute the following HIVE query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CurrentCostDataTemp ( sensor INT, temp FLOAT, ts TIMESTAMP, watt INT ) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1",
    "cassandra.port" = "9160",
    "cassandra.ks.name" = "EVENT_KS",
    "cassandra.ks.username" = "admin",
    "cassandra.ks.password" = "admin",
    "cassandra.cf.name" = "currentcostRealtime2_stream",
    "cassandra.columns.mapping" = "payload_sensor, payload_temp, payload_timestamp, payload_watt" );

select * from CurrentCostDataTemp;
```

.. but this gives only the following (see specific picture below) - e.g. that there is NO attribute level data that is shown. However, it is evident that there are EVENT_KS entries given it outputs 4 rows.. so question is how do I reference the data to extract the values, or is there something else going on here that I am not aware of?:

```
key sensor  temp    ts  watt
1402816273765::192.168.1.106::9443::52              
1402815283659::192.168.1.106::9443::51              
1402815238323::192.168.1.106::9443::49              
1402815280532::192.168.1.106::9443::50
```

Have verified that the data is in Cassandra by checking with Cqlsh - see here:

```
cqlsh:EVENT_KS> select * from "currentcostRealtime_stream";

 key                                    | Description                             | Name                       | Nick_Name            | StreamId                         | Timestamp     | Version | meta_ipAdd | payload_sensor | payload_temp | payload_timestamp   | payload_watt
----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------
 1402815283659::192.168.1.106::9443::51 | This is the Currentcost realtime stream | currentcostRealtime.stream | Currentcost Realtime | currentcostRealtime.stream:1.0.5 | 1402815283659 |   1.0.5 |       null |              1 |         18.7 | 2014-06-15 14:54:43 |            1
 1402815238323::192.168.1.106::9443::49 | This is the Currentcost realtime stream | currentcostRealtime.stream | Currentcost Realtime | currentcostRealtime.stream:1.0.5 | 1402815238323 |   1.0.5 |       null |              1 |         18.7 | 2014-06-15 14:53:58 |            1
 1402815280532::192.168.1.106::9443::50 | This is the Currentcost realtime stream | currentcostRealtime.stream | Currentcost Realtime | currentcostRealtime.stream:1.0.5 | 1402815280532 |   1.0.5 |       null |              1 |         18.7 | 2014-06-15 14:54:40 |            1
 1402816273765::192.168.1.106::9443::52 | This is the Currentcost realtime stream | currentcostRealtime.stream | Currentcost Realtime | currentcostRealtime.stream:1.0.5 | 1402816273765 |   1.0.5 |       null |              1 |         18.7 | 2014-06-15 15:11:13 |            1

(4 rows)

cqlsh:EVENT_KS>
```

Most likely a minor issue only that I have overseen, but would be great if someone else have seen this and could respond as well..

When adding in a remote table definition to MySQL DB externally, the tables and all are created, but it seems like the problem is getting to the attribute data in the EVENT_KS table itself, and having that created and accessed through the HIVE script.

Thanks in advance!

/Jorgen

***[UPDATE - Thursday 19th - SOLVED]*** Got it working with a few hints to this question. The following code works fine now, which is great.. greatly appreciated for the time to respond from you guys..

```
drop table CurrentCostDataTemp10;
drop table CurrentCostDataTemp_Summary10;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CurrentCostDataTemp10 ( messageRowID STRING, payload_sensor INT, messageTimestamp BIGINT, payload_temp FLOAT, payload_timestamp BIGINT, payload_timestampmysql STRING, payload_watt INT ) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1",
  "cassandra.port" = "9160",
  "cassandra.ks.name" = "EVENT_KS",
  "cassandra.ks.username" = "<USER>",
  "cassandra.ks.password" = "<PASSWORD>",
  "cassandra.cf.name" = "currentcostsimple5_stream",
  "cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key, payload_sensor, Timestamp, payload_temp, payload_timestamp, payload_timestampmysql, payload_watt" );

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CurrentCostDataTemp_Summary10 ( messageRowID STRING, payload_sensor INT, messageTimestamp BIGINT, payload_temp FLOAT, payload_timestamp BIGINT, payload_timestampmysql STRING, payload_watt INT ) 
STORED BY 'org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'mapred.jdbc.driver.class' = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
  'mapred.jdbc.url' = 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/currentcost' ,
  'mapred.jdbc.username' = '<USER>',
  'mapred.jdbc.password' = '<PASSWORD>',
  'hive.jdbc.update.on.duplicate'= 'true',
  'hive.jdbc.primary.key.fields' = 'messageRowID',
  'hive.jdbc.table.create.query' = 'CREATE TABLE CurrentCostDataTemp1 ( messageRowID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, payload_sensor TINYINT(4), messageTimestamp BIGINT, payload_temp FLOAT, payload_timestamp BIGINT, payload_timestampmysql DATETIME, payload_watt INT ) ');

insert overwrite table CurrentCostDataTemp_Summary10 select messageRowID, payload_sensor, messageTimestamp, payload_temp, payload_timestamp, payload_timestampmysql, payload_watt FROM CurrentCostDataTemp10;
```

[Using Different Reporting Frameworks with WSO2 Business Activity Monitor. By Sachini Jayasekara](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/using-different-reporting-frameworks-wso2-business-activity-monitor/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have amended your query as follows. Please try with that.

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CurrentCostDataTemp ( key string, sensor INT, temp FLOAT, ts TIMESTAMP, watt INT ) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1",
    "cassandra.port" = "9160",
    "cassandra.ks.name" = "EVENT_KS",
    "cassandra.ks.username" = "admin",
    "cassandra.ks.password" = "admin",
    "cassandra.cf.name" = "currentcostRealtime2_stream",
    "cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key,payload_sensor, payload_temp, payload_timestamp, payload_watt" );

select * from CurrentCostDataTemp;
```

Comment: Great - started testing based on what you guys noted, and ended up with something that worked (see below). This yields the right input data into MySQL, so getting closer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 1st line of the script as follows.

CREATE `EXTERNAL` TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CurrentCostDataTemp (`key STRING`, sensor INT, temp FLOAT, ts TIMESTAMP, watt INT)

(Remove `key STRING` part if it gives errors.)

Note: May be you will have to run `DROP TABLE CurrentCostDataTemp` before running above, in case it is already created, when you run it before.

Comment: Got it! Both responses gave me some pointers to try to update the e2e approach, and got it working.. included the solution above. Heaps thanks!